# Is there a tool or a simple PHP or Jquery solution to export all id's and Classes into a blank css Sheet?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, export

I swear I came across a tool that did this like a year ago and I cannot find it. I have searched and searched, especially here on stack, but nothing seems quite right.

Reason for this is to to create alternate style sheets for existing sites without having to empty out an existing style sheet etc. Thanks for any assistance!

Comment: You could probably write one really quick. You can match all classes / ids with this: Classes: `(?:class=["|']([a-z0-9-_ ]+)["|'])` ID: `(?:id=["|']([a-z0-9-_]+)["|'])`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Primer

> ...undercoats your CSS by pulling out all of your classes and id's and placing them into a starter stylesheet. Paste your HTML in to get started.

http://primercss.com

### Bear CSS

> ...is a handy little tool for web designers. It generates a CSS template containing all the HTML elements, classes & IDs defined in your markup.

http://bearcss.com/

Comment: As soon as I saw the bear I knew I was in the right place. Thank you for reading my mind. This is it!!!

Answer (score 1):

If you are not scared of programmatic solutions, it's super easy to write your own "parser" with jQuery:

```
$("*[id*=]").each( function() {
    if(this.id !== "") {
        console.log("."+this.id+" {");
        console.log("");
        console.log("} ");
        console.log("");
    }
});
```

Which incidentally can also be turned very easily into a bookmarklet with tools such as [this one](http://benalman.com/code/test/jquery-run-code-bookmarklet/):

```
javascript:(function(e,a,g,h,f,c,b,d){if(!(f=e.jQuery)||g>f.fn.jquery||h(f)){c=a.createElement("script");c.type="text/javascript";c.src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/"+g+"/jquery.min.js";c.onload=c.onreadystatechange=function(){if(!b&&(!(d=this.readyState)||d=="loaded"||d=="complete")){h((f=e.jQuery).noConflict(1),b=1);f(c).remove()}};a.documentElement.childNodes[0].appendChild(c)}})(window,document,"1.3.2",function($,L){$("*[id*=]").each( function() {if(this.id !== "") {console.log("."+this.id+" {");console.log("");console.log("} ");console.log("");}});});
```

Otherwise I'd recommend giving [this CSS generator](http://lab.xms.pl/css-generator/) a go or [bear CSS](http://bearcss.com/) like yckart suggests.

Answer (score 0):

Try the **CSS** button on http://spruce.flint.umich.edu/~jalarie/jaa_kcd2.htm